# Why === instead of == for undefined

Tags: javascript, typeof

Several sources suggest, that there are two canonical ways to check whether variable is undefined:

```
foo === undefined
typeof foo === 'undefined'
```

But can anyone explain, why would one use `===` instead of `==` ?

EDIT: the question is not about === vs ==. It is about using correct operator with the 'undefined'. The difference between === and == is obvious. But the question is which operator would be more correct when checking if value is undefined or not.

Comment: `===` compares type *first* then value.  `==` compares value and *may* convert the values so that the types match.

Comment: check this: http://stackoverflow.com/q/359494/798682

Comment: `==` performs type conversions to try and come up with a positive result. Especially for `typeof`, which only EVER returns a string, there's no need to convert types so why pay the overhead?

Comment: `null == undefined`, but `null !== undefined`.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Sure simple. You base it off which behaviour you want (below)

```
null == undefined // true
undefined === null // false
typeof undefined // 'undefined'
typeof null // 'object'
```

Comment: `undefined == null // true` right?

Comment: Yeah, all equality operators in JS are associative @elclanrs (note `b >= a` doesnt mean `a <= b` :P

Comment: @elclanrs Ahh, I see what you're pointing out. megawac, there's a typeo on the second line.

Answer (score 4):

=== is a strict comparison.  === not only compares values but also datatype for example:

```
"2" == 2 is true
"2" === 2 is false
```

Answer (score 2):

Looks like the question is not about the difference between `==` and `===` operators, but about in what situations one should use `=== undefined` comparison and when `typeof == 'unefined'`. Well..

There are two ways to check for undefined value.

The first way is using strict comparison operator `===` to compare with `undefined` primitive:

```
var a;
a === undefined; // true
```

Above comparison will work as expected, only if the variable is declared but has undefined value.
Note that if variable has never been declared you can't use `a === undefined` comparison because it will throw reference error:

```
a === undefined // ReferenceError: a is not defined
```

That's why in this case `typeof` comparison is bullet-proof:

```
typeof a == 'undefined' // true
```

which will work properly in both cases: if variable has never been assigned a value, and if its value is actually `undefined`.

One more example. If we want to check for a `prop` property which is/can be missing:

```
someObj.prop === undefined // ReferenceError: a is not defined
```

but

```
typeof someObj.prop == 'undefined' // true
```

Comment: As long as `someObj` has been defined then attempting to check if `someObj.prop === undefined` will not throw a reference error, it'll just return `true` or `false`

Comment: You are absolutely right. The question is NOT JUST about === vs ==. It is about using correct operator with the 'undefined'. It is a pity it got so many minuses since people rush to answer without thinking about the question.

Answer (score 0):

The === operator tests type as well as value. Using it consistently throughout your code helps to prevent a number of subtle and annoying errors, and is generally a Very Good Idea.

```
"5" == 5    // True, even though one is a string and the other a number
"5" === 5   // False because the two variables are of different type
```

While it's probably not strictly necessary when comparing to the special undefined property, it certainly doesn't hurt, and it's better to use === everywhere in your code than it would be to use === everywhere except for this corner case. Consistency is good.